# Complementarity between the laws of physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-gravity, quantum-interpretations

Is this following proposal plausible, worth considering, or dismissable as lunatic fringe science?

What if the universe isn't really what we think it is but some universal quantum computer where we read off one output at a time? This universal quantum computer is initialized to a superposition of program instructions -- which are identified with the laws of physics -- and after reading off one output after another, one finds there are in general two different kinds of questions we can ask; general relativity type questions, where we get GR type answers, and quantum mechanical type questions, where we get QM type answers. But we have to choose between one or the other, and whichever we choose, we get the answer appropriate for that domain. The place where both are united is the Planck scale, but unfortunately, the Planck scale as way too inaccessible to us, and is hence unobservable. Can this explain the confusion about UV/IR mixings?

String compactifications are computer programs determining the parameters of the effective field theory describing the domain of answerable experiments.

A complementarity between the laws of physics themselves. GR/QM complementarity.

Is there any flaw with my proposal?

Comment: Why would that matter? The laws are the laws and discovery of these leads to the projection of future hypothesis.

Comment: This would have to be far more precise to be appropriate for this site.